# Formula with two different objects

Tags: api, formula

I'm trying to write a formula that looks on object A for a specific word in a field, and if that is there, to than on object B take sales total minus the value tied to object A.
Here's what I have so far that fails: (ITEMCODE and UNITPRICE are from ObjectA)

```
IF(
    CONTAINS(Sage100_Invoice_Line_Items__r.CommercientSF8__ITEMCODE__c,"//VAT"
    (CommercientSF8__NONTAXABLESALESAMT__c - CommercientSF8__UNITPRICE__c)
)
```

Comment: You cannot loop through child records in a formula.

Comment: So is there anyway for me to accomplish this in a formula?

Comment: If you are open to managed packages you can use [Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) to determine how many such children there are, then in your formula check if that number equals 0.

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to managed packages you can use Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries to determine how many such children there are, then in your formula check if that number equals 0.